# Show that $P_Eh=h- \langle h,e_1 \rangle_1 - \langle h,e_2 \rangle e_2$ for $E=\{e_1,e_2\}^\perp$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In my homework I have a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Let $E=\{e_1,e_2\}^\perp$

then I have to show that:
$$P_Eh=h- \langle h,e_1 \rangle_1 - \langle h,e_2 \rangle e_2$$

I know that $E$ is closed but not sure how that helps. I also know that for all $e_n$ with $n>2$ they are perpendicular to $E$.

Any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $P_E(h)$ is the unique element of $E$ such that $h=P_E(h)+u_h$ where $u_h$ is orthogonal to $E$.

$\langle h-\langle h,e_1\rangle e_1-\langle h,e_2\rangle e_2,e_i\rangle=0, i=1,2$ implies that $P_E(h)\in E$ and $u_h=-\langle h,e_1\rangle e_1-\langle h,e_2\rangle e_2$ is orthogonal to $E$.

Comment: What they are doing is setting the two first coordinates of h to zero, so that h is orthogonal to F?

Wouldn't it be easier just to set:
$$P_Eh=h \cdot \text{"identity-matrix with zeros in the two first entires of the diagonal"}$$

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer states the $P_E(h)$ is the unique element such that

> $P_E(h)\in E$ and $(h-P_E(h))\in E^{\perp}$ holds.

In our case $E=\{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp}$.

Lets first notice that

$$\{e_1,e_2\}\in\{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp \perp}$$
which implies that

> $$span\{e_1,e_2\}\subset \{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp \perp}$$

Notice then that

$$\{e_1,e_2\}\subset span\{e_1,e_2\}$$
$$\implies  span\{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp} \subset \{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp}$$
$$\implies \{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp \perp} \subset span\{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp \perp}=span\{e_1,e_2\}$$

We then conclude that

> $$span\{e_1,e_2\}=\{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp \perp}=E^{\perp}$$

Now, remembering that since we are dealing with an Orthonormal System we can write:

$$h=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,e_j\rangle e_j $$
we see that 
$$P_Eh=h- \langle h,e_1 \rangle_1 - \langle h,e_2 \rangle e_2=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\langle h,e_j\rangle e_j - \langle h,e_1 \rangle_1 - \langle h,e_2 \rangle e_2$$
$$=\sum_{j=3}^{\infty}\langle h,e_j\rangle e_j\in span\{e_j,j\in\mathbb N,j>2\}=span\{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp}$$

> $$P_Eh\in E\supset span\{e_1,e_2\}^{\perp}$$

And now 
$$h-P_Eh=\langle h,e_1 \rangle_1 +\langle h,e_2 \rangle e_2$$
which clearly belongs to the $span\{e_1,e_2\}=E^{\perp}$

---

We conclude that

$$P_E(h)=(h- \langle h,e_1 \rangle_1 - \langle h,e_2 \rangle e_2) \in E$$
and
$$h-P_E(h)=(\langle h,e_1 \rangle_1 +\langle h,e_2 \rangle e_2)\in E^{\perp}$$

And with that we are done.